# MVC Themes and DatePicker

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I have an MVC project that I have created and implemented a bootstrap theme and incorporated a datepicker however I would like to change the theme of the datepicker.

I am using Entity Framework and changed my theme by downloading a new bootstrap.css. I really like how the theme's looks however when I add the datepicker it was not I was expecting. I think it goes with the theme of the bootstrap.css. However from what I can tell I have my datepicker pointing to a different .css . I cannot find any reference to datepicker in the bootstrap.css

In my BundleConfig I have added the following -

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/all/css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

and then in my _Layout.cshtml I added the following Render items

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/OpenBurn.js")
```

then I created the OpenBurn.js that executes the datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[type='datetime']").each(function () {
       $(this).datepicker();
    });
})
```

My question is how do I change the theme of the datapicker?

Answer (score 0):

If you download your theme from jQuery([theme downloads](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000000&zThemeParams=5d000001000006000000000000003d8888d844329a8dfe02723de3e5701cc8cb8a0f4166c8f002bb384a9a94d46b66930ecd1d30314057ff273da42b76034e7df160b9e7ba7002682805fc5802b2a0549efda864da8b438712e9bef7a29f310d784ca8e76257cb28631219c7679208574244410acc6727fec193d1573927af926d67c3e660b43f7c8bf602dd021ad1cb24c1f878791ccf352a6c341568bf5fd453a295fc09f90cd484980973a509ee6371eeed5f3d4e3ffe695dbe6d28d00093dc8428765479cfce85044dc818006ff9d8c56f4043ee49abd518b26039da59f89d15c120e1c42e968ecfd452d846d1df4a98933339513d8a445bff35d4798015a4eed3c2cf70de93df820a0c3ecea3d3c846332fe3aa3914992945e6b31137ea89633f6360a363c9608733b7a27c988aa6b2044a311e4d7d868627c8e19cf44aaae49ab3bc0de9a483f8cd374dd812f4d136e20ac351ee609209fe547de6e1dc40790664a1fd9205222d5eaa6fe2a30f79248e4706b0a52475c2432512baa84ea1e43dcab18ae777f41cf397125bdc6e0c3be6ff89ea3d5ba4ccc1855a9187077dde1db47379d4d5446ee99ff85fd1c8b42161912aaef5b6e40bfd16ed5b2c9c639e7de394ddfec2d73092d6f350b338053db0529fc1777889b65915eb73bbdcf0b88eb822af679a6160bcac21088b608516ac47d95cc1c313430c204d06b0b1e14d3b3b9794e420e89cd0f70a47a640b0e5995743747a9483b97081e8de543e11d881ff59770200)), make sure you uncheck everything except for the datepicker widget, download the file, extract all, copy everything from the file named jquery-ui.theme.css, and paste it into a separate file (ex. datepicker.darkui.css) and then add it to your bundle config or drop it right on the page.

Here's my page:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/datepicker.darkui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue be specifying a datepicker theme. I selected a datepicker theme and put the css file under my 'Contents' folder - ui_1.10.4_themes_smoothness_jquery-ui.css

Then in my BundleConfig.cs I referred to it first before the overall page themes.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/ui_1.10.4_themes_smoothness_jquery-ui.css",
                 "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
                 "~/Content/themes/base/all/css",
                 "~/Content/site.css"));
```